# CAS can not get the TGT in version of 6.0.3

Tags: java, cas

1.I add the rest support in my cas-server project pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-support-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.restart the cas-server then use postman to request TGT with params username and password

```
request url:https://localhost:8443/cas_server_war/v1/tickets?username=admin&password=admin
result:the rest API return https://localhost:8443/cas_server_war/v1/tickets/TGT-3-mXFuG9GXw9iMeXYa1pBACKww9JsgdsxUBDb0dV0zv0yhzUVyUVTFjnR6Q95k7Fh0534DESKTOP-97IVFIA
```

3.use the url that returned in step2 and the param 
service=https://www.baidu.com to get the ST,it should return the body like "ST-3-W9WaFfn2xUlTesZYtNejSW8yKRoDESKTOP-97IVFIA" to me ,but it's result is none(this is my log):

```
2019-05-19 19:00:04,849 INFO [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: admin
WHAT: [status=200-OK,body=ST-3-W9WaFfn2xUlTesZYtNejSW8yKRoDESKTOP-97IVFIA]
ACTION: REST_API_SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sun May 19 19:00:04 CST 2019
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================
```

4.There is no problem in version of 5.3.1(I successfully get the ST in version of 5.3.1)

Thank you Very much!

Comment: Hi @peng, I see  that you seemingly posted 3 question with regards to the same problem. Best if you close 2 of them so the answer can be focus on only one question. There is an edit button on your post, so you can edit your question instead of submitting a new one. Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much